# Debugger gives a segmentation error for strlen

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, initialization, c-strings

In the code below the debugger shows no error but when I run this piece of code inside a function scope `char *s` is also in the function scope the debugger gives a segmentation error for the `strlen` function. Would adding `char *s` as a parameter solve the problem? Or is it something else?

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define SIZE1 100
#define SIZE2 2000

int main() {
    const char *getFileExtension(const char *filename);
    char tags[100][2000]; 
    char files[100][2000]; 
    char paths[100][2000];
    char textfiles[100][2000];
    char orph[100][2000];
    int i, j, k = 0;
    char *s;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++) {
        if (strncmp(getFileExtension(files[i]), "txt", 3) == 0) {
            strcpy(textfiles[k], files[i]);
            k++;
        }
    }
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE1; j++) {
            if (strcmp(tags[i], textfiles[j]) != 0) {
                snprintf(s, strlen(tags[i]), "%s", tags[i]);
                s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';
                strcpy(orph[k], s);
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

const char *getFileExtension(const char *filename) {
    const char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
    if (!dot || dot == filename) 
        return "";
    return dot + 1;
}
```

**EDIT**: after initializing `char *s` and the other arrays I ran my code on devc++ and [www.onlinegdb.com](http://www.onlinegdb.com). It kept giving me a segmentation fault on devc++ but the code worked on the website.

Comment: You have about 1Mb of arrays on the stack, which will break some systems.

Comment: Aside: if you are going to `#define SIZE1 100` and `#define SIZE2 2000` then please *use* them in the array definitions, like `char tags[SIZE1][SIZE2]; `

Comment: `char *s;` has no memory allocated. So `snprintf(s,strlen(tags[i]),"%s",tags[i]);` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I suggest compiling with these flags: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -g -fsanitize=address,undefined` - It should prevent the above from even compiling until you fix the obvious errors and mistakes and it will also give you runtime support to crash with nice pointers to where it went bad.

Comment: *the code worked on the website.* you cannot tell what the code does: there is no input or output... the compiler could optimize the whole program down to the final`return 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared uninitialized arrays

```
  char tags[100][2000]; 
  char files[100][2000]; 
  char paths[100][2000];
  char textfiles[100][2000];
  char orph[100][2000];
```

So using them in standard C string functions like for example

```
           if(strcmp(tags[i],textfiles[j])!=0)
            {
              snprintf(s,strlen(tags[i]),"%s",tags[i]);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

It seems the function `getFileExtension` also does not set elements of the array `files` in this call.

```
getFileExtension(files[i])
```

Also the pointer s

```
  char *s;
```

used in this statement

```
snprintf(s,strlen(tags[i]),"%s",tags[i]);
```

also has an indeterminate value.

Answer (score 0):

your tags array is not initialized. so strlen has undefined behavior. snprintf requires the size of available space not the length of the (uninitialized) contents. you should use sizeof instead of strlen in the snprintf call.

The 2nd argument to snprintf is the size which was allocated to the first argument. But you allocated nothing.

Comment: i did it but i still get a segmentation fault on the same line

Comment: in this snprintf you copy tags[i] to the memory pointed to by s. where is this memory that points to? what size is it? you should declare s as char s[size big enough] and use sizeof(s) which is equal to <size big enough >

Comment: alternatively you can use malloc() to initialize s to a big enough chunk of memory.